# Identify these seeds

Tags: identification, seeds

I moved my home office last week and was unpacking a few boxes when I ran across a ziplock bag my mother gave me a few years back. It contained a few seeds (pictures attached).

Each seed is about a 1/4 inch long and a 1/8 inch wide. The seeds all had brownish colored wings which I clean off and throw away. I should have kept a few of the seeds whole for better identification purposes. I do not know what kind of seeds they are.

Each seed has a light colored brown cover on the back of the seed and the front side is a darker brown color. I am not sure the seeds are viable any longer but I will try to germinate them to see what they become. If anyone has any identification help that would be great.

[image: unknown seed closeup]
[image: unknown seed]

Comment: winged seeds are usually some sort of tree. often a canopy tree.